# How to install Gnome3 on Lubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, gnome, lubuntu, lxde

I am running Lubuntu, which uses LXDE (based on Openbox) instead of Gnome and I want to install Gnome3 on it. I have tested the following PPA, but it doesn't work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

What I have installed is a broken Gnome3, no special effects, no beautiful windows border, I guess it may lack something (I have installed Gnome3 before, so I did know how Gnome3 looks like). Can anyone give me a hand? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that PPA doesnt have any packages for 10.10 - typo in your title?

Comment: If it is a type I was the one that added the 10.10 tag. So it might be a typo but let's wait for the OP to answer. Although I just checked another question from the OP and it mentions Lubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I think a more relevant question is: Why install a distro that's built around LXDE and then place Gnome3 on top of it?  Much simpler to install mainline if you're looking to use Gnome as a WM and just disable services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PPA you are using only supports 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04. It does not support 10.10 as the image suggests:

Precise - 12.04
Oneric - 11.10
Natty - 11.04

[image]

Your best bet would be to upgrade to at least 11.04 and then apply this PPA. But I would recommend waiting for 12.04 which would have a much better support (not to mention the enhance performance and up-to-date code).